# C++ multi-stage linking

Tags: c++, linker, g++, libraries

Ok, so this might not be a great question, but I'm a bit stuck.

I have 3 programs:

> pegio.c/pegio.h - Does hardware initialization and functions for my device
>
> PegIOHandler.cpp/PegIOHandler.h - Handles I/O for device
>
> PegRTU.cpp - Main function

My project implements the opendnp3 (which allows one to transmit data using the DNP3 protocol) library.
Now, to compile it I first compile the pegio.c file

```
gcc -c pegio.c -o pegio.o
```

Easy, up to here I understand.

Secondly I compile the IOHandler and reference pegio.c as it uses it.

```
g++ -c PegIOHandler.cpp pegio.c -o PegIOHandler.o -std=c++0x
```

Now it gives me the following output.

> g++: warning: pegio.o: linker input file unused because linking not done

But, it still creates the object file. HOWEVER, PegIOHandler implements opendnp3 header files, which is included in PegIOHandler.cpp and PegIOHandler.h. When I attempt to compile these files without using the '-c', it tells me that there are undefined references to the opendnp3 files. I know I have to link them to my project, but how do I do that?

Then compililing my third and final file:

```
g++ PegRTU.cpp pegio.o PegIOHandler.o -o pegrtu -std=c++0x
```

This now tells me that there are undefined references to the opendnp3 files.
So: How do I link the opendnp3 library to my project / code files???
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ouch. So many misunderstandings. You don't need the previously compiled object files to compile further source files to object code. However, you do need to link them together at the end of the compilation process, including any libraries required. All in all:

```
gcc -c pegio.c -o pegio.o
g++ -c PegIOHandler.cpp -o PegIOHandler.o -std=c++0x
g++ -c PegRTU.cpp -o PegRTU.o -std=c++0x
g++ -o executable_name *.o -lopendnp3 # or whatever linker flag is needed for OpenDNP3
```

And ***pretty please,*** [read this.](http://faculty.cs.niu.edu/~mcmahon/CS241/Notes/compile.html)